# How to remove a Binding without clearing the current value?

Tags: data-binding, uwp, unbind

Say I have a `TextBlock` named`textBlock1` whose `TextProperty` is bound with another `TextBox`

To unbind the TextProperty, I have to do this:

```
textBlock1.ClearValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

But doing that, I also erase the current text, which I don't want. I just want the `TextBlock`'s text to stop changing when the property-it's-bound-to changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you just set its value like this:

```
textBlock1.Text = textBlock1.Text;
```

Setting the *string* should destroy the binding.

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman You always can remember the current value it temporary variable, then use CLearValue, then use the temporary variable to set back the correct value.